# Google Maps Api, get locations from a route drawed on a map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The idea is simple, but I can't find information or examples. I want that the user to draw a route in the map and then be capable of getting the info of locations and addresses in data structure like an array, or json.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex.html

The above link is an example of what you're looking for, have a look at the source code it seems pretty straight forward.  This example is for Google Maps api v3

You can retrieve the points using the Polyline,getPoints() method.

Comment: Thanks!!! Yes, is pretty straight forward. I will try to implement something with this example.